# Setup a simultaion on a custom map in Indigo

Tags: simulation, rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone. A newcomer to ROS here.
How can I setup a simulation in indigo distribution. I want the result to look something like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezor8R3JEOM
I wanted to use turtlebot simultaion, but apparently it is not supported in indigo yet. What is the easiest way to setup a simulation with the vizualization process  (in rviz, possibly)? How can I load the custom map? Do I have to use Gazebo?

I appreciate the answers very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193956/setup-a-simultaion-on-a-custom-map-in-indigo/) by [vd77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20364/vd77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-10-01**:
Do you need 2D or 3D simulation? You can use Stage or gazebo.

**Comment by [vd77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20364/vd77/) on 2014-10-02**:
2D would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For 2D simulation you should use Stage. You have to set you .world file, maybe using an image. Then you could use an existing robot model or create a new one. Stage node will publish topics for position, laser data, camera data, and it subscribe to velocity topic. You can use another node for controlling the robot via cmd_vel topic, like teleoperation using the keyboard. Finally, you can start RVIZ and visualize data in topics aforementioned. There are tutorials and guides for each of the nodes and functionalities described.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0